# error when playing next video in service using app overlay : Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Tags: java, android-studio

i want to show video using app overly. first time i show the video in service it works fine but when i click on next or previous controller button in service which is currently playing video over other app it crashes with the error
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Comment: i think the problrm is generated by following LOC  
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path.get(pos)));
it executes sucessfully first time but when click on next button second time app crashes

Comment: while debugging i got to know that my WhatsApp videos are playing in mini player but camera video are not playing it crashes the app....